# What is the C++ equivalent of PHP's is_dir()?

Tags: c++, linux, directory, filesystems

What is the C++ equivalent of PHP's is_dir() ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

> bool is_dir ( string $filename )   
> Tells whether the given filename is a directory.

Working on a Linux platform only, what library would you use?

And what if cross-platform support mattered, what method would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX function `lstat` (and its less secure friend `stat`) returns a `struct` that you can query for that information. A convenience macro is provided: `S_ISDIR()`  `man 2 lstat` for usage information.

Boost also provides the [filesystem](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) library, which provides an easy-to-use set of functions, including the free function `is_directory()`.

Comment: `stat()` isn't "less secure", it's just... different.

Comment: @caf: Well, a lot of security issues I come across in software relate to programs that misuse `stat` and end up opening themselves up to symlink attacks. `lstat` simply doesn't follow symlinks and so it doesn't suffer that particular class of attacks.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing in the C++ standard to deal with filesystems across platforms.  For cross platform filesystem access, use the Boost Filesystem library.